# Ubuntu 20.10 No bootable Device

Tags: 20.10

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10 on my notebook. I chose delete Windows and just install Ubuntu on the notebook. However, when I reboot the computer, the screen display "No bootable Device".
By the way, the computer seems not have UEFI. I didn't see the option on Bios.

Answer (score 0):

When installing ubuntu, you should make sure the grub installation location is on your ssd. Else, you get issues like this. I recommend reinstalling ubuntu, and by using custom partitioning, you can change your grub installation location to your ssd. (if you have a hard drive, change every time I say "ssd" to "harddisk".) Note: you should then also change the mounting point of your partition to "/" and format your partition to "ext4"

Comment: In fact, I have re-installed two times, but it also display No bootable Device. I think the reason is the computer doesn't have UEFI mode to boot ?

Comment: Or there have any way to use grub but doesn't need to use UEFI?

Comment: I have UEFI, and I use GRUB for my dual boot. You need UEFI to boot to anything, except on old computers, then you need BIOS